# How do you update a UTextureRenderTarget2D in C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, texture2d, rendertarget

I'm referenced @J. Rehbein's ask.
[How do you update a UTextureRenderTarget2D dynamically in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638346/how-do-you-update-a-utexturerendertarget2d-dynamically-in-c)

And use public modules ("Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "UMG", "GameplayTasks", "Landscape", "RHI", "RenderCore").

Why printed assertion failed log?

How fix assertion failed problem?

Please, teachers.

```
void AWorldCreator::BeginPlay()
{
 Super::BeginPlay();
 if (RenderTarget != nullptr) {
   RenderTarget->InitCustomFormat(Width, Height, PF_B8G8R8A8, true);

   auto region = FUpdateTextureRegion2D(0, 0, 0, 0, Width, Height);

   FTexture2DRHIRef TextureRHI = RenderTarget->GameThread_GetRenderTargetResource()->GetRenderTargetTexture();

   ENQUEUE_RENDER_COMMAND(UpdateTextureRegionsData)(
   [=](FRHICommandListImmediate& RHICmdList)
     {
       check(TextureRHI.IsValid());  // Assertion failed line
     });
 }
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want change URenderTargetTexture2D's texture. i'm tried how that use 2_DrawMaterial.
And i feel hardness from how convert UMaterialInstanceDynamic to UMaterialInterface.
So, next tried how that use ENQUEUE_RENDER_COMMAND. Blocked again.
So I posted a question.
Sorry and thanks everyone for read my awkward(weird?) question.

...

I succeed URenderTargetTexture2D updating without ENQUEUE_RENDER_COMMAND.
I converted UMaterialInstanceDynamic to UMaterialInterface thought UStaticMeshComponent.
I use UStaticMeshComponent's functions (GetMaterial, SetMaterial).

```
UMaterialInstanceDynamic* DynamicMaterial = UMaterialInstanceDynamic::Create(Material, GetWorld());
...
StaticMeshComponent->SetMaterial(0, DynamicMaterial);
...
canvas->K2_DrawMaterial(StaticMeshComponent->GetMaterial(0), Position, Size, CoordinatePosition);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Texture->UpdateResource();
Texture->UpdateResourceImmediate(false);
```

Comment: Thank you! but, sorry. I don't know how. \n
RenderTarget->InitCustomFormat(Width, Height, PF_B8G8R8A8, true);
RenderTarget->UpdateResource();
RenderTarget->UpdateResourceImmediate(false);

I try  this code. but failed.
Please detailed answer me. please.